# Calculus (what is y when x is?)

Tags: calculus, integration

Given $y>0$ and
$$dy/dx = (3x^2+4x)/y$$

If the point $(1,rad10)$

is on the graph relating x and y, then what is $y$ when $x=0$?

I'm not sure whether or not to integrate, or just plug in the point or something.

Comment: In the language of separable DE, we have $y\,dy=(3x^2+4x)\,dx$. Integrate both sides.

Comment: language of what?

Comment: Have you solved differential equations by separation of variables?

Comment: @AndréNicolas i think i understand what you did. but what does $ydy$ mean? edit: guess not lol. i just finished precalculus

Comment: It basically doe not really mean anything, but it is a step in the one of the usual solutions.

Comment: so where do i go from $x^3+2x^2$?

Comment: What is rad 10?

Comment: the sqrt of 10.

Answer (score 2):

Rewrite the equation as $$y\frac{dy}{dx}=3x^2+4x^2.$$

Note that
$$y\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{d}{dx}\left(\frac{y^2}{2}\right),$$
by the Chain Rule.  So the derivative of $\frac{y^2}{2}$ is $3x^2+4x$. It follows that
$$\frac{y^2}{2}=x^3+2x^2+C,$$
for some constant $C$.

Use the value of $y$ when $x=1$ to evaluate $C$. Now we know everything.

Answer (score 0):

Rearranging:
$$ydy=(3x^2+4x)dx$$
Integrate:
$$\int ydy=\int(3x^2+4x)dx$$
$$\frac{y^2}2=x^3+2x^2+C$$
Put $(1,rad10)$ to get the value of C, then put $x=0$ to get y

Answer (score 0):

$\dfrac{dy}{dx}=\dfrac{3x^2+4x}{y}$

Now cross-multiply to get: $y\,\mathrm{d}y=3x^2+4x\,\mathrm{d}x$.

Integrate on both sides to get: $\frac{1}{2}y^2=x^3+2x^2+C$.

Multiply by two on both sides to get: $y^2=2x^3+4x^2+C$.

Now solve for $C$ by plugging in the coordinate pair $(1, \sqrt{10})$: $10=2\cdot1^3+4\cdot1^2+C$ gives $C=10-2-4=4$.

$y^2$ becomes: $y^2=2x^3+4x^2+4$

Now plug in $x=0$ to get $y^2=4$, so $\boxed{y=2}$.

Comment: How do you go from ydy to 1/2?

Comment: Unfortunately that isn't the answer

Comment: It must be $\frac{1}{2}y^2$. I will edit.

Comment: Is $y=2$ the right answer?

Comment: Yes the answer is 2.